# JS Навигация по массиву с динамической глубиной

Tags: javascript, массивы, рекурсия, динамические-массивы

Ребята, возник вопрос по навигации по массиву (казалось бы!). Поиск не удался, т.к. запутся и не понимаю, как правильно задать вопрос.

Вобщем задача.

Делаю компонент перетаскиваемого и сортируемого дерева на vue по примеру react компонента

[image: VueNestable]

[image: VueNestable]

структура данных - массив объектов с вложенными дочерними массивами и т.д.

```
// примерная структура
const items = [
  {
    _path: [0],
    title: "[0]",
    children:[
      {
        _path: [0,0],
        title: "[0,0]",
        children: []
      },
      {
        _path: [0,1],
        title: "[0,1]",
        children: [
          {
            _path: [0,1,0],
            title: "[0,1,0]",
            children: [/* ... */]
          }
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
  /* ... */
]
```

Вложенность может быть разной. 
Элемент имеет параметр `_path` - массив с его "адресом" в струтуре
Как самым красивым образом обратиться к элементу по его `_path` ?

Например, из любого источника мы получаем `_path=[0,2]`, как вы понимаете, в коде писать `items[_path[0]].children[_path[1]]` совсем не вариант. А если глубина 5 или 10?
Буду благодарен любому совету))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function getElement(tree, path) {
   return getElement(tree[path.shift()].children, path); 
}
```

Только **обязательно** клонируйте path перед вызовом функции, так как массивы передаются по ссылке, а функция меняет переданный в нее path.

Ну и я бы добавил проверки параметров, если есть вероятность невалидных данных в самом дереве.

Comment: Спасибо за наводку)) Еще небольшой вопрос (уже подтупливаю).
Как теперь заменить весь корневой элемент (это поддержка реактивности Vue).
Полагаю надо клонировать корневой объект со всей струтурой, добраться до последнего объекта в дереве, сделать изменения и заменить корневой элемент при помощи `splice()`

Comment: @МаксимК, к сожалению не работал с Vue. Не очень понимаю, что именно нужно сделать.

Comment: Ну да ладно)) И на том спасибо.))